# how to cancel last subscription in paypal using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

Hi i am using recurring paypal subscription button that works perfectly.But i want to know the way to cancel last subscription of same user.

Explanation:

I have  1 user,3 users and 6 users plans.

I did the subscription part for all types now what i want:

lets say user change from one user to three users
and go to payment screen to upgrade
Will the last subscription will end automatically or not.

i found  this code for cancel subscription:

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_subscr-find&alias=SGGGX43FAKKXN">
```

this is the code i use for subscription button that works perfectly:

```
 protected void btnsubscribe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal amt = 0;
    if (ddlPlanType.SelectedValue.ToString() != "6")
    {
        amt = Convert.ToDecimal(ddlPlanType.SelectedValue);
    }
    else
    {
        int userNo = 0;
        if (txtusers.Text.Trim() != "")
            userNo = Convert.ToInt32(txtusers.Text);
        amt = Convert.ToDecimal(ddlPlanType.Items[2].Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(10.95 * userNo);
    }
    int qty = Convert.ToInt32(rdoplantype.SelectedValue);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("business=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paypalemail"].ToString());
    sb.Append("&return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessURL"].ToString());
    sb.Append("&cancel_return=" + Server.UrlEncode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedURL"].ToString()));
    sb.Append("&button_subtype=services&upload=1&no_note=1&rm=2");
    sb.Append("&currency_code=USD&cmd=_xclick-subscriptions&src=1&modify=0&item_number=Standard&p3=1");
    if (qty == 1)
    {
        Server.UrlEncode(sb.AppendFormat("&t3={0}",  "M").ToString());
        Server.UrlEncode(sb.AppendFormat("&a3={0}", amt).ToString());
    }
    else if (qty == 12)
    {

        Server.UrlEncode(sb.AppendFormat("&t3={0}",  "Y").ToString());
        Server.UrlEncode(sb.AppendFormat("&a3={0}", amt*12).ToString());
    }
    Server.UrlEncode(sb.AppendFormat("&item_name={0}", ddlPlanType.SelectedItem.Text + " " + txtusers.Text).ToString());
    Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalUrl"].ToString() + sb.ToString());
    Response.Redirect("Success.aspx");
}
```

Does this code works for cancel last subscription?

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_subscr-find&alias=SGGGX43FAKKXN">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code does not actually cancel the subscription. This example was taken from the docuentation:

```
<A HREF="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_subscr-find&alias=alice%40mystore%2ecom"><IMG BORDER="0"SRC="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_unsubscribe_LG.gif"></A>
```

It displays an "Unsubscribe" button image to the user that links to the subscription cancellation function on the PayPal website. the user must log into their PayPal account to continue. the email address or payer ID here:

```
cmd=_subscr-find&alias=alice%40mystore%2ecom
```

is identifying you as the subscription provider to be cancelled. they will have to click another "Unsubscribe" button here to complete the process.

Comment: thanks for your reply.According to doc i have to pass current user email in alias.Right???

Comment: previous answer was incorrect. have another look at above. the value should be the email address or payer ID that identifies the subscription providers account

Comment: ok that will be for single user,But how we will pass when everytime there will be different-2 users login,then how we pass alias here.

Comment: you will present the same button to all subscribers because the code identifies YOU as the subscription provider when you replace 'alice%40mystore%2ecom' with 'SGGGX43FAKKXN', which I assume is your payer ID.

Comment: yes i know there will be same button for all subscribers,but email will be different for each subscriber.so how i will pass that for each user???

Comment: have a look at [Canceling Multiple Subscriptions at One Time](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_websitepaymentsstandard_integrationguide.pdf#G6.2068215) if you want to cancel more than 1 subscription at a time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56791/discussion-between-sikha-and-keving).

Comment: what i have to when there will different payerid??how i can pass that at run time.because there can be so many users login on website.

Comment: are you available  KevinG?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_subscr-find&alias=SGGGX43FAKKXN">
    <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_unsubscribe_LG.gif" BORDER="0">
</a>
```

This HTML makes it very easy for us to create an Unsubscribe button and place it wherever we want. Before we can use this, though, we need to make one change to the href attribute. At the end of the URL for the href, you’ll see alias=SGGGX43FAKKXN. This alias parameter is defined by PayPal as “the secure merchant account ID of the subscription provider’s PayPal account. This value is in the My business info section of your PayPal account profile.” Replace the value SGGGX43FAKKXN with your own ID.